# Trying to resolve dependency on libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.9)

Tags: centos, 64bit, x86

A friend built an EPUB converter for me that depends on `lib64png16_16`.  `lib64png16_16` has a dependency on `libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.9)(64bit)`.  I pulled down and compiled `ZLIB_1.2.11`, but it's not being recognized as a solution (and make install doesn't put it in `/usr/lib64`).

Does anyone how I can either (a) get an RPM of `libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.9)(64bit)` for x86_64/CentOS7, or (b) tell me how to compile `libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.11)(64bit)`?  Silly me, I thought that compiling it on a 64 bit system would result in the 64bit version.

P.S., the CentOS ZLIB package is 1.2.7.  I can't find one for 1.2.9 or better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prepend the `lib` directory of where you compiled and built `ZLIB_1.2.11` to `your LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

For example, I compiled and built it like this:

I created these directories

```
/opt/zlib/1.2.11

/opt/zlib/src
```

I then moved into `/opt/zlib/src` and:

```
 wget https://github.com/madler/zlib/archive/v1.2.11.tar.gz
```

I then decompressed it and moved into the directory containing the config just as I'm sure you did and then ran this:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/zlib/1.2.11
```

Then I ran `make` and `make install`.

That put the libraries in:

```
/opt/zlib/1.2.11/lib
```

I then ran this command to see `ZLIB_1.2.9` available:

```
strings -d /opt/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.so | grep ^ZLIB
```

Lastly, I ran this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/zlib/1.2.11/lib:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

In your case, you will run this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/zlib/lib:/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Obviously, you will replace `/path/to/zlib/lib` with the path to the location of the `zlib 1.2.11` libraries.